# IHTTPActionResult custom response and unit testing with WebApi 2

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, mstest, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a class which is as follows

```
public class Response<T> : IHttpActionResult where T : class
   {
      private readonly T _body;

      ....
      public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      {
        HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage();

        switch (_httpStatus)
        {
            case HttpResponseStatus.Ok:
            {
                msg = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _body);
                break;
            }
             case HttpResponseStatus.BadRequest:
            {
                msg = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, _body);
                break;
            }
            ...
            return Task.FromResult(msg);

      }
   }
```

This is my base class for returning IHTTPActionResult in my web api calls.
It works well for what i require it for.

I now have some unit tests setup using MSTest.

```
            // Act
            IHttpActionResult result = controller.Step1();  


            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result, "Is null when it shouldnt be");
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(Response<BodyContent<LogingActivityResult>>), "Is not expected IsInstanceOfType");
```

Both of these Assertions work fine.
However i now want to actually get @ the data held within my response and assert that they are ok i.e.: correct values, counts, etc but am having no luck with this.
I have tried ALL the various System.Web.Http.Results types such as

```
var contentResult = result as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Response<BodyContent<LogingActivityResult>>>;
```

or

```
var contentResult = result as FormattedContentResult<Response<BodyContent<LogingActivityResult>>>;
```

but both of these are null when i hover over contentResult variable.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Immediate Window -> `result.GetType()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this.. the property _body in my above class was set to PRIVATE, as a result I could not access this in my unit test class. Setting it to PUBLIC solved it and was able to access the data being returned in the response.